# Angular not working correctly with Meteor 1.3.1

Tags: angularjs, meteor, angular-meteor

I am following [www.angular-meteor.com](http://www.angular-meteor.com) tutorial on a windows computer.

But when I run `meteor` in console I only see:
[image]

A blank screen besides `socially`...

So it seems like some angular packages does not work with `Meteor 1.3.1`.

Here is output from `meteor list`:

```
accounts-password               1.1.7  Password support for accounts
angular                         1.3.9_2  Everything you need to use Angu...
angularui:angular-google-maps   2.3.2  angular-google-maps (official)
angularui:angular-ui-bootstrap  0.13.0  Native AngularJS (Angular) direc...
angularui:angular-ui-router     0.2.15  angular-ui-router (official): Fl...
angularutils:pagination         0.9.1_2  Magical automatic pagination fo...
check                           1.1.3  Check whether a value matches a p...
dotansimha:accounts-ui-angular  0.0.4  AngularJS wrapper for Meteor's Ac...
email                           1.0.11  Send email messages
es5-shim                        4.5.9  Shims and polyfills to improve EC...
jquery                          1.11.7  Manipulate the DOM using CSS sel...
less                            2.5.7  Leaner CSS language
meteor-base                     1.0.3  Packages that every Meteor app needs
mobile-experience               1.0.3  Packages for a great mobile user ...
mongo                           1.1.6  Adaptor for using MongoDB and Min...
reactive-var                    1.0.8  Reactive variable
standard-minifier-css           1.0.5  Standard css minifier used with M...
standard-minifier-js            1.0.5  Standard javascript minifiers use...
tmeasday:publish-counts         0.7.3  Publish the count of a cursor, in...
tracker                         1.0.12  Dependency tracker to allow reac...
twbs:bootstrap                  3.3.6  The most popular front-end framew...
```

For example `angularui:angular-ui-router` seems not be working. But it works with `meteor 1.2` version.

Is there someone out there that have the same problem? Maybe a solution as well?
Best Regards

`EDIT`

Removing `dotansimha:accounts-ui-angular` resulted in that I can see the map and search box. But The app is still broken. No `parties` are shown, pagination does not work and so on... Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I got it working now:

`meteor list`

```
accounts-password               1.1.7  Password support for accounts
angular-meteor-auth             1.0.1  Angular-Meteor authentication module
angular-templates               1.0.2  Compile angular templates into th...
angular:angular                 1.5.3_1  AngularJS (official) release. F...
angularui:angular-google-maps   2.3.2  angular-google-maps (official)
angularui:angular-ui-bootstrap  0.13.0  Native AngularJS (Angular) direc...
angularui:angular-ui-router     0.2.15  angular-ui-router (official): Fl...
angularutils:pagination         0.9.1_2  Magical automatic pagination fo...
check                           1.1.3  Check whether a value matches a p...
dotansimha:accounts-ui-angular  0.0.4  AngularJS wrapper for Meteor's Ac...
email                           1.0.11  Send email messages
es5-shim                        4.5.9  Shims and polyfills to improve EC...
jquery                          1.11.7  Manipulate the DOM using CSS sel...
less                            2.5.7  Leaner CSS language
meteor-base                     1.0.3  Packages that every Meteor app needs
mobile-experience               1.0.3  Packages for a great mobile user ...
modules                         0.5.2  CommonJS module system
mongo                           1.1.6  Adaptor for using MongoDB and Min...
pbastowski:angular-babel        1.3.2  Babel compiler and ng-annotate fo...
reactive-var                    1.0.8  Reactive variable
standard-minifier-css           1.0.5  Standard css minifier used with M...
standard-minifier-js            1.0.5  Standard javascript minifiers use...
tmeasday:publish-counts         0.7.3  Publish the count of a cursor, in...
tracker                         1.0.12  Dependency tracker to allow reac...
twbs:bootstrap                  3.3.6  The most popular front-end framew...
```

So I do use `accounts-ui-angular`!

I followed [this link](https://github.com/Urigo/angular-meteor/issues/1277)

What I did was:

`First`:

1. Remove the angular meteor package you installed via atmosphere: meteor remove angular
2. Make sure you have the ecmascript package installed. If you had the atmosphere angular package installed previously you may have removed it after getting a notice that multiple compilers were trying to handle files with .js extension. So check out meteor list and if ecmascript isn't there do: meteor add ecmascript
3. Install angular and angular meteor via npm: npm install angular angular-meteor --save
4. List 'angular-meteor' as a module dependency for your main module: angular.module('myApp', ['angular-meteor']);
5. meteor remove ecmascript
6. meteor add modules (ecmascript implies modules so you have to add it manually if you remove ecma)
7. meteor add pbastowski:angular-babel

Note that I `do not` need to import angular in app.js (no `import angular from 'angular';` or `import 'angular-meteor';`)

Now:
[image]

Hope that helps if someone have the same problem:)

Answer (score 0):

I found that the problem is the incompatibility with this package:

```
meteor remove dotansimha:accounts-ui-angular
```

**Don't forget to remove the dependency 'accounts.ui' on 'app.js'**

Just removed and the result:

[image]

**Possibly the problem is why somehow this package uses the "blaze-html-templates"**

Comment: What do u want to know?:) the code is available as zip at www.angular-meteor.com tutorial step 17:)

Comment: Pops up some error on your console? I'm going to download the .zip file here and test it

Comment: See if that explanation helps!

Comment: Thanks! Can see the map now but the app is still broken. See `Edit` above.