# Using npm on Meteor 1.3 + angular1 (bump!)

Tags: angularjs, meteor, requirejs, angular-meteor

**Edit note:** 
I am changing this question as I progress. Will continue to update.

I've upgraded my angular-meteor project (Meteor 1.2.1 + jade + ES6 js) to 1.3. The update was successful and everything works as before. I'd like to start using npm to install angular plugins as in:

```
meteor npm i <package>
```

As a first step, I've installed angular and angular-meteor:

```
meteor npm i angular --save
meteor npm i angular-meteor --save
```

then added:

```
import angular from 'angular';
import 'angular-meteor';
```

I've got a few  missing packages errors on the server side, and fixed those by adding them using `npm i <package> --save`

Now I'm bumping against:

```
Error: Can't find npm module 'ecmascript'. Did you forget to call 'Npm.depends' in package.js within the 'modules-runtime' package?
W20160410-21:27:53.530(3)? (STDERR)     at Object.Npm.require (/Users/user/work/myproj/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:195:17)
```

Ideas?

**Update**

I assumed that adding ecmascript would fix it, but the error happens when it's installed. To be clear, I wasn't sure if to `meteor add ecmascript` or to `meteor npm i ecmascript` so tried both, separately and together. Nether fixed the above error.

That being said, `meteor add ecmascript` actually got ES6 errors to stop, so I know it's there and active

**2nd-Update (3 weeks later)**

Waiting and retrying the update after a couple of weeks solved it: I've run `Meteor update` then run the server, which in turn errored a few times about missing npm packages but after `[meteor] npm install` of those, everything worked like a charm. Problem solved!

Comment: How do you bundle / transpile your code? I guess you have a reference to app.js on your html file(which should be loaded async using some systemjs / webpack etc), or you miss configured your bundler / transpiler. Please provide more info.

Comment: I count on `Meteor` to bundle and transpile the code/templates. Meteor version 1.2.1 did that perfectly, it also does so after upgrade to 1.3. I use es6 syntax in the JS, and jade. Those still transpile after the upgrade to Meteor 1.3, but after I added the `import angular` statements, both Jade and ES6 syntax broke

Comment: Can you try this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/a/36494987/1426570

Answer (score 1):

In previous version of Meteor Angular we removed `ecmascript` if you're migrating, add it back

```
meteor add ecmascript
```

Comment: I thought so as well, but it didn't fix the error - see updated comment

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps that worked for me: 
1. meteor update 
2. review the packages that did not upgrade and upgraded them. Specifically the ones shown bellow:

The following top-level dependencies were not updated to the very latest version available:
 * angular 1.3.7 (1.3.10 is available)
 * angular-meteor-auth 0.2.2 (1.0.2_1 is available)

Newer versions of the following indirect dependencies are available:
 * angular-meteor-data 0.3.0 (1.3.10 is available)
 * angular-templates 1.0.1 (1.0.2 is available)
* pbastowski:angular-babel@1.3.4

3. meteor npm init (and fill all details)
4. npm install --save angular angular-meteor
5. added the following import on app.js (main app file): import angular from 'angular';
   (I added also import angularMeteor from 'angular-meteor';, but it does not seem to be necessary).
6. I received one strict-di error which I fixed by adding 'ngInject'; to that function (RoutingHandler).

That made my project work as before (no new npm packages, no extra imports).